# Code-behind check to see if a control has been set to display: none?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have a control that is being hidden on my server side using `dropdown.hide();`.

`hide()` is a server-side method I created to hide my methods, e.g.

```
control.Style["display"] = "none";
```

How can I tell, on the server-side, if my control is hidden or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't mean just doing:

```
if (control.Style["display"] == "none") { .... }
```

And that you want to know after a postback?  If that's the case, then you can't do it, unless you store the fact it's hidden in a hidden input or something like that, using JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Just check if `control.Style["display"] == "none"`

If it is changed on the clientside you have to save the state so it will be sent by the POST action. You can save the state in a hiddenfield or using AJAX?